# How to Filter DataView WebPart (DVWP) from Query String?

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part

I have a Web part page which has two web part.

1) Visual Web part Containing Drop Down List. Drop Down is filled with data from column of Pages Library.

2) DVWP pulls data from Pages Library.

Now When user selects any item from Drop Down I want to filter DVWP based on query string passed from selected value of Drop Down.

I found some Links but not able to perform the operation. I want complete solution Step by Step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have a working data view webpart:

1. Open SharePoint designer and the page that the data view web part exists on
2. From the Options tab of the Data View Tools section in the ribbon, select Parameters
   [image: Parameters button in ribbon]
3. Create a new parameter of type Query String - specifiy the parameter name, the query string variable name (what its called in the URL), and the default value (for when no value is supplied)

   [image: Query String Parameter Configuration]
4. From the Options tab of the Data View Tools section in the ribbon, select Filters
   [image: Filter button in ribbon]
5. Set up the filter to use your parameter (QueryParameter will be the parameter name you supplied)

   [image: Filter configuration]

If you have problems with the steps above, I'll add that I always start with an empty data view web part and then manually add the data source and columns to it through the menus and XSLT. I find that this route tends causes me less trouble than adding a data view web part with the data source directly attached.