# Filtering datas

Tags: data-view-web-part, external-content-type, soap, oracle, bdc

I want to filter datas.

I have a data view with 3 column (name,department,foreign languages)by a **SOAP Connection** but I can't make any filtering for foreign languages.

I have a html form web part for filtering and it needs connection with a list and I can't do it with a data view. So I need to create an external content type. When I click on external content types, it says

> There is no Business Data Connectivity Service associated ith the
>   current web context.

First I have to connect to BDC for connecting to an Oracle client but I can't.

I have installed **Oracle 10gR2client** on **64 bit Win Server 2012** and copy-past sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora at oracle's path but my **oracle client is 32 bit**. When I try to connect to data source by username and password at BDC Meta Man, it says

> The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnnection' threw an exception.

How can I solve this oracle problem? Or is there a way to make filtering data view ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I succeed by editing data view. I followed this question [How to Filter DataView WebPart (DVWP) from Query String?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55184/how-to-filter-dataview-webpart-dvwp-from-query-string)

I created a new page and create my data view there again and did the things what has been told at the answer.My QueryParameters were ready at web source.

Then under data view tools at SPDesigner, I selected Option>Grouping Toolbar. And my code edited automatically.The QueryParameters were displayed in dropdownlist. Then I started to edit the code to make it a very simple filtering.